# PROLOG store previous outputs/inputs and generate new input based on old

Tags: prolog

What im trying to do is:

getDiffAnswer/5

getDiffAnswer(Q,PQ,PR,CR,R) holds if R is the new response from the list containing the candidate answers CR for the the question Q.

Q is a Question.

PQ is a list of previous Questions

PR is a list of previous Replies

CR is a list of possible Replies

R is the different Reply

Expected output:

```
1. ?- getDiffAnswer([what,is,X],
[],[],
[1,2,3],R).
R = 1;
false.

2. ?- getDiffAnswer([what,is,X],
[[what,is,X]],
[[1]],
[1,2,3],R).
R = 2 ;
false.

3. ?- getDiffAnswer([what,is,X],
[[what,is,X],[what,is,X]],
[[1,2]],
[1,2,3],R)
R = 3 ;

4. ?- getDiffAnswer([what,is,X],
[[what,is,X],[what,is,X],[what,is,X]],
[[1,2,3]],
[1,2,3],R)
false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is edited answer, the first approach with select was wrong. This approach is to make recursion and check if another questions are equal to our question, if they are we are collecting answers to this questions. At the end we know that our answer R will be member of set CR but it also wont be member of collected set.

```
getDiffAnswer(Q,PQ,PR,CR,R) :-
    possibleAnswers(Q,PQ,PR,[],Rs),
    member(R,CR),not(member(R,Rs)).

possibleAnswers(_,[],_,RS,RS).
possibleAnswers(Q,[H|L],[H1|L1],Rs,Rs2):-
    (Q = H -> append([H1],Rs,Rs3)),
    possibleAnswers(Q,L,L1,Rs3,Rs2).
```

Rs is just a set of all answers already used for the current question.

I am treating PR like list of answers, so it's not `[[1,2,3]]` but `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all questions are always the same, then this implements your specification I believe:

```
getDiffAnswer(_,_,PR,CR,R) :-
  append(PR,[R|_],CR).
```

Your examples:

```
?- getDiffAnswer([what,is,'X'],[],[],[1,2,3],R).
R = 1.

?- getDiffAnswer([what,is,'X'],[[what,is,'X']],[1],[1,2,3],R).
R = 2.

?- getDiffAnswer([what,is,'X'],[[what,is,'X'],[what,is,'X']],[1,2],[1,2,3],R).
R = 3.

?- getDiffAnswer([what,is,'X'],[[what,is,'X'],[what,is,'X'],[what,is,'X']],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],R).
false.
```

Comment: This fails if the PR (3rd argument) is not in order,  getDiffAnswer([what,is,'X'],[[what,is,'X']],[2],[1,2,3],R).  
false.

Comment: @Alejandro: yes of course. You should have specified they could be in any order.